# Is "resource/1/edit" RESTful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I've been reading up on REST lately and it's become seemingly clear that *verbs* do not belong in URIs. If this is the case, is the standard "resource/1/edit/" that particularly shows up in Rails a violation of REST? And if so, what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse CRUD with REST.

Rails provides "Resourceful Routing", and the actions within the URL simply provide a resourceful interface. The HTTP request verbiage still remains RESTful, which is what counts.

[Here](http://nicksda.apotomo.de/2010/10/rails-misapprehensions-crud-is-not-rest/) is an insightful article which does a fairly good job explaining REST/CRUD (specifically in Rails).